# How the equals() method works

Tags: java, equals

I am digging into the basics of Java. I infer from [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273/index.html), that the Java 'equals' method means, if two objects are equal then they must have the same hashCode().

Here's my example.

```
public class Equals {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = new String("a");
        String b = new String("a");
        System.out.println("a.hashCode() "+a.hashCode());
        System.out.println("b.hashCode() "+b.hashCode());
        System.out.println(a == b);
        System.out.println(a.equals(b));
    }

}
```

**Output:**

a.hashCode() 97 
b.hashCode() 97 
false 
true

The actual Java language 'equals' method:

```
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
  }
```

In my above example, *a.equals(b)* has returned true, meaning the condition 'a==b' is satisfied. But then why is 'a==b' returning false in that example?

Aren't hashCode and address one and same? Also, is 'hashCode' compared when we say 'a==b' or something else?

Comment: Don't get distracted by the hash code. It's not the determiner of equality. Ask yourself, how many hash codes can there be if the resut is an integer? Now how many strings can there be?

Comment: Hashcode != Address.  Hashcode value is commonly used as an index in a hash table, but it is also often overridden to produce better hash.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `String` class has overridden the `equals()` method. Please follow the [String equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) documentation.

*a.equals(b) has returned true, meaning the condition a==b is satisfied*

This is the default implementation of `equals()` in the `Object` class, and the `String` class has overridden the default implementation. It returns true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

*Aren't hashCode and address one and same?*

Not necessarily. For further reading on [hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29).

Comment: Java documentation states : "As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language.)" [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)

Answer (score 4):

The `==` operator in Java compares object references to see if they refer to the same object.  Because your variables `a` and `b` refer to different objects, they are not equal according to `==`.

And the `hashCode` method doesn't return the address in `String`, because that class has [overridden `hashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29).

Additionally, the [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method has been implemented in `String` to compare the contents of the strings; that's why `a.equals(b)` returns `true` here.

Answer (score 3):

**No, Hashcode and address aren't the same.**

Because a==b is not comparing hashcodes.

**Yes, something else is compared when we say a==b.**

(that's not addresses either, really, but it's close enough).

**Also, just because "equal objects have equal hashcodes" does not mean "equal hashcodes means equal objects".**

Answer (score 1):

a.equals(b) is different from a==b.

a.equals(b) checks if two objects are equals based on equals() implementation.

a==b checks if two objects have same reference.

If a==b is true then a.equals(b) must be true because they are referencing to the same object but not vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

String class **overrides the default implementation of the equals()** method of the Object class. The equals method code that you have provided is not from String class but from the Object class, which is overridden be the String class implementation which **checks if the contents of the two objects are same or not.**

Answer (score 1):

Hashcode for an object is meant to be overridden.

For String class the formula used is as follows:

s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]

I encourage you to search why 31 has been used as a multiplier and not some other number.

A general thumb rule for overriding hash code is that for different objects hash code should be different as far as possible.

To achieve this it is advisable that you take into account every significant field of an object while calculating the hash value.

Note: Just an unrelated food for thought (source : Effective Java):
Consider the following implementation of hashcode

```
int hashcode(){
     return 10;
}
```

This is a valid implementation but it is also the worst possible one. Read about why.

Comment: That is equally bad, if not worse. Returning same value every time defeats the purpose of hash code.

Answer (score 0):

A and B are two separate objects that generate the same hash code because of `String`'s implementation of `hashCode()`.  `==` just checks to see if the left and right sides share the same reference.  It does not call an `Object`'s `equals()` method.

So, no, hashes and object references are *not* the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestEquals {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = new String("a"); 
        String b = new String("a");
        System.out.println("a.hashCode() " + a.hashCode());
        System.out.println("b.hashCode() " + b.hashCode());

        // Checks the reference which is something like the 
        // address & address is different from hash code which can be overriden
        System.out.println(a == b);

        // It returns true if and only if the argument is not null 
        // and is a String object that represents the same sequence 
        // of characters as this object. (String Implementation of equals)
        System.out.println(a.equals(b));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a.hashCode() 97
b.hashCode() 97
false
true
```