# How does the equals work in java?

Tags: java

```
class A 
{ 
   int a=10,b=10,c=10; 
} 
class Equals 
{ 
     public static void main(String s[]) 
   { 
     A a,b; 
     a=new A(); 
     b=new A(); 
     if(a.equals(b))
      {

         System.out.println("We r same..."); 
      }
     else
         {

          System.out.println("We r not same...");

         } 
    } 
}
```

Why is this code not printing output as `we r same`?
I am not able to understand the logic behind this program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How equals() method works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089282/how-equals-method-works)

Answer (score 2):

Those to objects are not same because you are checking reference equality.  you have to use `equals()` method.

Add this to your `class A` :

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        A ref = (A)obj;
        return ref.a == this.a && ref.b == this.b && ref.c == this.c ;
    }
```

And instead of writing `a==b` check `a.equals(b)`

Answer (score 1):

By default the `equals` method will return whether the two objects are actually the same. In your case they are different, hence the output.

You can look at this this way -  you haven't told what do you consider as "equality" of your object `A`.

The way to solve it would be to implement `equals` method for your `A` class.

Answer (score 1):

This is because '==' operator checks only that both objects are referencing the same memory or not. If both are referencing same location, it returns true.

For ex : `a=new A();
            b=a;`

Then, a==b returns true, because both are pointing same location.

Comment: What about the equals?

Comment: equals also do same thing. But in String class it is overridden. That's why it checks value of String object not their memory references.

Comment: I've just given u String class example. You can override equals() in your class. This function is specially built by JAVA since operator overloading is not there in JAVA.

Comment: please accept the answer, so that it'll help others

Answer (score 0):

Equals() in java compares objects to see if they're the same object somewhat. The two objects you created have different references so equals will not return a true. Misread this the first time.

Answer (score 0):

The `equals` is an method inherited from `object`, you can override it as you need.

```
class A 
{ 
   public int a=10,b=10,c=10;
   public boolean equals(Object a){
     if(a == null) return false;
     if(!(s instance A)) return false;
     A other = (A)a;
     if(other.a == this.a && other.b = this.b && other.c == other.c)
       return true;
     return false;
   }
}
```

see [Overriding the java equals() method quirk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185937/overriding-the-java-equals-method-quirk).

Answer (score 0):

a and b are different instances of class A. why do you think they should equal to each other because they have the same class?

you should override equals method in class A to implement your own logic for determine if two instances of class A equal to each other or not. for example:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (o==null) return false;
     A o2 = (A) o;
     return this.a == o2.a && this.b == o2.b && this.c == o2.c;
}
```