# Check if two objects have the same attributes

Tags: java, object, attributes, boolean

Hello I want to compare if two objects have the same attributes
I create John and John2 , when comparing John to John 2 it is false, and comparing John to John himself is true, why is that ?

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student John = new Student("John", 15);
        Student John2 = new Student("John", 15);

        System.out.println(John.equals(John2)); // FALSE why ?
        System.out.println(John.equals(John)); // TRUE 
    }

}
```

.

```
public class Student {

    String name;
    int age;

    public Student(String name, int age) {

        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public boolean egal(Student c) {

        return ((this.name).equals(c.name) && (this.age) == (c.age));
    }
}
```

Comment: See [How equals method works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089282/how-equals-method-works)

Answer (score 4):

Because you are using default `equals()` method instead of the method you created `egal()`. If you call `egal()` you see desired output.

Or instead of creating a new `egal()` method ovverride existing equal method in your class.

Comment: To make the compiler help you about small typos like yours, you can attach `@Override` to your `egal() / equals()` method definition, telling the compiler that this method isn't something newly invented, but meant to define class-specific behaviour for something defined elsewhere.